# With CTE why i am not able to print 1 to 1000 number or more but 1 to 100 i am able to print

Tags: sql-server

```
with cte
as
(select 1 number
union all 
select number+1 from cte where number <1000)
select * from cte
```

Its showing error:

> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: use `maxrecursion` hint

Comment: okk thanks .. Its working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you the problemhere, by default a CTE has a maximum recursion of 100. This is intentional, as it's stops a poorly coded CTE taking out your server and grinding it to a halt.

You can increase that value by using `OPTION MAXRECURSION`. Thus, in simple terms:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 1 AS I
    UNION ALL
    SELECT I + 1 AS I
    FROM CTE
    WHERE I + 1 <= 1000)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000);
```

This is all covered in the CTE documentation: [Using MAXRECURSION to cancel a statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#g-using-maxrecursion-to-cancel-a-statement)